# Find a proper subfield of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/J3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

How do you find the proper subfield of $\mathbb{Z}[i]/J3$? I have tried, but I can't figure out the method.

Here $J$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ generated by $p$ when $p$ is an irreducible Gaussian integer; $p=3$.

Comment: Are we supposed to grab our crystal ball and guess what J3 means?!

Comment: And what does "Jacobian 3" mean in the context of the Gaussian integers $\;\Bbb Z[i]\;$

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not clear, what $J3$ could mean. I would think that we talk about
$$
\mathbb{Z}[i]/(3)\simeq \mathbb{F}_3[x]/(x^2+1),
$$
which 
is a finite field with $9$ elements. Now it is easy to find a proper subfield - take $\mathbb{F}_3$, for example.

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why $(3)$ is a maximal ideal too.

Comment: Yes, because $3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which is a PID, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer.